# mapbox number of items returned by getJSON

Tags: mapbox, geojson

I am placing multiple Clustered locations on the map. How can I retrieve number of total of featured returned?

Here is my code:

```html
<script>
$.getJSON("datafile.json", function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'circle-stroked', 'marker-color': '59245f'}));
  var popUp="pouptext";
        layer.bindPopup(popUp,{
        closeButton: true,
        minWidth: 320
    });
      }
    });
    markers.addLayer(geojson);
 var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets') .setView([42, -90], 4);
    baseLayer.addTo(map);
    markers.addTo(map);
  });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: why - this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `datafile.json` contains a GeoJSON FeatureCollection, the number of features would be stored in the `data.features.length` property.

Comment: OK I think I found the problem.

Comment: OK Thanks to tmcw, his answer did work.

First I tried to insert another variable itemsFound=data.features.length; inside the code, and then print it out, but items were loaded with ajax, so total was printing 0 on page load. I added a code to send data.features.length; inside the getJSON and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK Thanks to tmcw, his answer did work.

First I tried to insert another variable **itemsFound=data.features.length;** inside the code, and then print it out, but items were loaded with ajax, so total was printing 0 on page load. I added a code to send **data.features.length;** inside the getJSON and it worked fine.